# HTML input text field value. Problem reading operator '>'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having problems in retrieving the value of an input text element.

The input is something like: 10>Foo

and the code is like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < form.inputElemName.value.length;i++){
       document.write(form.inputElemName.value.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

The output that I get is: 10
instead of the whole string: 10>Foo

But the strangest part is that if I add a space character before each input character, like the following:

```
for(var i = 0; i < form.inputElemName.value.length;i++){
       document.write(' '+form.inputElemName.value.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

it works and outputs:  1 0 > F o o

Any suggestions?
Thanks very much.

Comment: You could insert a '\' before each '>' character. I don't know what method you'd use (I don't do much JS/HTML), but I'm pretty sure that'd fix it.

Comment: Please be sure to at least add javascript to the tag, or mention that it's javascript code in those blocks. (it *is* javascript, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser probably notices that there is a sudden erroneus `>` character, and will in some case just 'fix' that outright.

Be sure to replace the values in the string with safe values before you display it.
If you want to display a `<` in a html page, use `&lt;` 
of if you want to display a `>` in a html page, use `&gt;`

```
var text = form.inputElemName.value;
text.replace("<", "&lt;");
text.replace(">", "&gt;");
document.write(text);
```

Comment: you have some typos (`&rt;` instead of `&gt;`, the variable is called `text` not `str`... that sort of thing) but otherwise awesome

Comment: any time :) i do it frequently... still not fixed though... `&rt;` should be `&gt;`

Comment: still! second para., last word.

Comment: still! says `&rt` when it should say `&gt`

Comment: i can't see it here. just says text.replace(">", "&gt;");

Comment: in the description; "if you want to display a `>` in a html page, use `&rt;`"

Answer (score 3):

You have to escape the HTML entities before writing plain text in document.
You can find an encoder/decoder there: http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

Answer (score 0):

@Timothy Groote and @user734702, here is what I did in console for Chrome,

```
var a = '10>Foo'; //You can put form.inputElemName.value here.
for(var i = 0; i < a.length;i++){
       document.write(a.substring(i, i+1));
}
```

More over can you check if there is only one input variable named **inputElemName** in just one form named **form** in your document.

Comment: Doing it in chrome's console will work just fine, since you're not messing with the DOM.
In the question however, the user was using `document.write`, which causes changes to the DOM.